# Is it possible to use a pear package without pear itself?

Tags: pear

Honestly, I know nothing about pear (... installation and all). But I know that there are MANY useful functions available through pear. I wonder if it is possible to use a source file out of the repository and use it with complete disregard for the rest of pear?

What I mean is "is it **technically** possible to use a source file out of the repository and use it with complete disregard for the rest of pear?

For instance Zend Framework offers canned functionality too, but the packages are so tightly interleaved that you simply cannot use a source file in isolation and have to include many others on which it depends. Well, does the same, or a similar condition exist with pear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the package - it may or may not utilise functionality in the base PEAR classes, such as throwing PEAR_Exceptions, making use of the PEAR registry and so on.

Honestly, you are far better off installing the package through pear than downloading the source code and manually extracting it to some directory inside your include_path. By using the pear installer to set up the package you won't waste time later on should you need to install a later version or manage dependencies between various packages - just let the installer take care of it.

Comment: Thanks you kguest. That was to be expected, that there is no universal rule and it depends on the package. One disadvantage of downloading manually as you say is you will have to manage dependencies and revisit the issue if you want to upgrade. But still I am more comfortable with this method than installing the whole pear. When all I need is a screw driver, I do not take all the tools in the DIY shop ;) - Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you adhere to the particular license expressed in the module for which you're using the source code from.

Here's an example of one that I looked at randomly from the [Calendar](http://pear.php.net/package/Calendar/download) module:

> LICENSE: Redistribution and use in
>   source and binary forms, with or
>   without   modification, are permitted
>   provided that the following conditions
>   are met:
>
> 1. **Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
>       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.**
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>       documentation and/or other materials provided with the
>      distribution.
> 3. **The name of the author may not be used to endorse or promote products
>       derived from this software without specific prior written
>      permission**.
>
>    @category  Date and Time
>
>    @package   Calendar
>
>    @author    Harry Fuecks
>
>    @author    Lorenzo Alberton
>
>    @copyright 2003-2007 Harry Fuecks, Lorenzo Alberton
>
>    @license   http://www.debian.org/misc/bsd.license  BSD License (3 Clause)
>
>    @version   CVS: $Id: Calendar.php,v 1.9 2008/11/15 21:21:42 quipo Exp $
>
>    @link      http://pear.php.net/package/Calendar

Comment: Thanks Mike, for pointing that out. From what I see they have adopted a license with which it is easy to abide. Anyway what I asked should be read "I wonder if it is possible to ...". I will edit my question to make it clearer. - Thanks again.